# How to slice only defined values?

Tags: perl, perl-data-structures

I can slice kes/values as next:

```perl
$item->%{ @cols }
```

But if some column does not exist at `$item` It will be created at resulting hash.

Can I slice only defined values?

Comment: Have you tried `no autovivification;`?

Comment: @tobyink, The issue isn't autovivification but the creation of hash elements when they are accidentally used as lvalues. `no autovivification;` won't help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can check whether they exist.

```
$item->%{ grep {exists $item->{$_}} @cols }
```

should do the job slicing only the existing values.

Anyway - simply accessing these values should NOT autovivify them. Only if you Pass these values as parameters to some function and they are implicetly aliased there, they are autovivified.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my @cols =qw (a b c);
my $item = [{a => 1, c => 3}];

print Dumper({$item->[0]->%{ grep {exists $item->[0]->{$_}} @cols }});
print Dumper($item);

print Dumper({$item->[0]->%{ @cols }});
print Dumper($item);

print Dumper($item->[0]->%{ grep {exists $item->[0]->{$_}} @cols });
print Dumper($item);

print Dumper($item->[0]->%{ @cols }); ## Only here does autovivication take place
print Dumper($item);
```

Only the last print will generate the:

```
$VAR1 = [
          {
            'c' => 3,
            'a' => 1,
            'b' => undef
          }
        ];
```

indicating that b got autovivified.

Comment: It seems that `->[0]` is excess at examples

Comment: I defined (in the example script) $item as an array of hashes, just to show that this works on any data structure as complex as it might be.

Answer (score 4):

Use

```perl
$item->%{ grep { exists($item->{$_}) } @cols }
```

or

```perl
do { $item->%{ @cols } }
```

---

Indexing/slicing a hash does not add elements to it.

```perl
my @cols = qw( a b c );
my $item = { };
say 0+%$item;                     # 0
my @kvs = $item->%{ @cols };
say 0+%$item;                     # 0 ok
```

Except when it's used as an lvalue (assignable value, such as when on the left-hand side of `=`).

```perl
my @cols = qw( a b c );
my $item = { };
say 0+%$item;                     # 0
1 for $item->%{ @cols };
say 0+%$item;                     # 3 XXX
```

You could filter out the keys of elements that don't exist.

```perl
my @cols = qw( a b c );
my $item = { };
say 0+%$item;                     # 0
1 for $item->%{ grep { exists($item->{$_}) } @cols };
say 0+%$item;                     # 0 ok
```

But the simple solution is to not use it as an lvalue.

```perl
my @cols = qw( a b c );
my $item = { };
say 0+%$item;                     # 0
1 for do { $item->%{ @cols } };
say 0+%$item;                     # 0 ok
```